# Visual Studio Code multiline select until a character

Tags: visual-studio-code, multiline

I would like to select all the words at once between the backtick. In MACOSX use <kbd>alt</kbd>+ <kbd>shift</kbd> and the cursor put a multi cursor at the beginning of the words but I can't stop the selection to the "`" character where the word ends.

```
  `apples` int(200) NOT NULL,
  `bananas` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `mangos` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `kiwi` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `raspberry` int(100) NOT NULL,
```

Is there a way I can select until some character is found in the line where the cursor is placed?
In this case, the expected selection is:

```
  `apples` 
  `bananas`
  `mangos`
  `kiwi`
  `raspberry`
```

Comment: Note: I don't think atl+shift is limited to MacOS. I've used it on Ubuntu and IIRC, also on Windows. There are keybindings that aren't the same on different platforms/keyboards, but I don't think alt+shift is one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open the find widget.
- Type `` `.*?` `` in regex mode (`.*` icon).
- Press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to select all occurrences.
- Press <kbd>esc</kbd> to close the find widget.

[image]

Comment: It does not seems to work, I have got a cursor for each letter...

Comment: @GM probably you had a typo in the regex. See this for demo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ulyig.gif

Comment: Thanks, that's works for the example even though the word must be enclosed between to spearator

Comment: @GM You can use a regex like this instead for that: ```(?<=`).*?(?=`)```

Comment: Works great! You can also match an arbitrary number of rows of something like string_to_remove,string_to_keep with `.*?,`

Answer (score 1):

If there is a dedicate way to select until a specific character, I am not aware of it.

However, you have a very regular "input" here (none of the fruit words have spaces in them). If that's representative of your real scenario, then to select apples, bananas, mangos, kiwi, raspberry, then put the caret right at the beginning of "`apple`", then hold <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> and click the beginning of "raspberry", then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>, then <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> (Windows and Ubuntu. I think for MacOS it's <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> then <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>, but I'm not 100% sure).

This doesn't work if the fruit words have spaces in them. In that case, if you happen to be doing this because you want to do find and replace, you can use the regular expression mode of the find and replace feature. Something like find `` ^  `([^`]+)` `` and then replace withsome usage of `$1`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it suits the example, and it is a good workaround, so it is not possible to select until a character... maybe this should be clarified at the beginning

Comment: @GM updated to clarify at beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by)

Create a keybinding:

```
  {
    "key": "shift+alt+]",  // or any other combo
    "command": "selectby.regex",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
      "forward": "('''|\"\"\"|'|\"|`)",
      "forwardNext": "{{1}}",
      "forwardInclude": false,
      "forwardNextInclude": false
    }
  }
```

Place multiple cursors before the strings you want to select, and press the key binding.

Answer (score 1):

If you do this selection frequently you can make a keybinding for it using this extension: [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform) (which I wrote).  Sample keybinding - in your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key": "alt+d",                 // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "find": "(?<=`)(.*)(?=`)",
    "restrictFind": "selections",
    "isRegex": true
  },
}
```

For this you just need to select the lines you want changed - it can be one selection, see demo.  Or you could use this option:

```
"restrictFind": "line",
```

and just put a cursor on any lines you want changed - the cursor can go anywhere on the line.

[image: select in backticksticks demo]

By `"line"`:

[image: select in backticks by line demo]